# How do you use and array to set Access VBA properties?

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties

I am trying to set up an array in Access VBA.  I have 40 different parameters to set and setting them using:
'ParameterName1.Visible = True...
'ParameterName2.Visible = True...

is rather clunky.  I believe it can be done with an array such as:

'for i = 1 to 40
'    ParameterName(i).Visible = True
'Next i

I am a novice in Access vba.  I have done some simple coding but this is my first attempt at arrays

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim NewPN As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ParameterName(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim ParameterNominal(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim ParameterMinimum(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim ParameterMaximum(1 To 10) As Variant

NewPN = MsgBox("Is This A New Part Number?", vbYesNo, "New Part Number")

If NewPN = True Then
    For i = 1 To 10
        ParameterName(i).Visible = False
        ParameterNominal(i).Visible = False
        ParameterMinimum(i).Visible = False
        ParameterMaximum(i).Visible = False
    Next i


ParaQty = InputBox("How many parameters will be measured?", Parameters?")

For i = 1 To ParaQty

    ParameterName(i) = InputBox("Please Enter the Name for Parameter
    (Include Units, if applicable) " & i, "Parameter Name?")
    ParameterNominal(i) = InputBox("Please Enter the Nominal Value 
    for Parameter " & i, "Nominal Parameter?")
    ParameterMinimum(i) = InputBox("Please Enter the Minimun Value for
    Parameter " & i, "Minimum Parameter?")
    ParameterMaximum(i) = InputBox("Please Enter the Maximum Value for  
    Parameter " & i, "Maximum Parameter?")

Next i
End If


End Sub
```

I get a "object required" error message on the first pass of the for/next loop.

Comment: What exactly are your parameters? `.Visible` is for form controls, e.g. text boxes. I'm pretty sure that you don't need all that code, instead you should use a continuous form for data entry. Entering lots of data through InputBoxes is a pain - if you get the 27th value wrong, you are screwed.

Comment: I am using a form to set measurement parameters for up to 40 different parameters.  There are a maximum of 10 measurements with 4 parameters each (Name, Nominal Value, Minimum Value and Maximum value).  These will be stored in there own table and accessed by the part number that is being measured. I was hoping to ask the user for 1) the number of parameters to be measured( ParameterName) and 2) have them input the Name, Nominal Value, Minimum Value and Maximum value for each of these Parameters.

Comment: You haven't explained what you want to achieve with `.Visible = False`. But again, don't use InputBoxes for that. Your users will hate you.